# What is the derivative of path independent line integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

We have that for every closed curve of finite length $\gamma$ in space $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$ \oint_\gamma Pdx + Qdy + Rdz = 0 \tag{1} $$

where $P=P(x,y,z), Q=Q(x,y,z), R=R(x,y,z)$ are functions.

We define

$$ u(M) \equiv \int_{M_0}^M Pdx + Qdy + Rdz  \tag{2} $$

where $M_0 = M_0 (x,y,z), M = M(x,y,z)$ are points. It follows from $(1)$ that any line integral over a finite-length curve is path independent, so $u(M)$ is well-defined.

I need to show

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = P, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = Q, \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = R. \tag{3}$$

What idea do I need to use?

Comment: Use the definition of the (partial) derivatives, using infinitesimal increments, and move $M$.

Comment: Isn't (1) only true for conservative vector fields?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, it is. I meant that it is known for this problem.